# JavaFX and CSS: Prevent CSS inheritence for inner TabPane

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I would like to have two styles for `TabPane`s in my application. For that reason, I written these CSS selectors:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .tab-header-background (...)
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator (...)
.tab-pane > .tab-content-area(...)
.tab (...)
.tab .tab-label (...)
.tab:selected (...)
.tab:hover (...)
.tab:selected .tab-label (...)
.tab:hover .tab-label (...)
.tab:hover (...)
```

In addition, I introduced a new `.main-tab-pane` class that defined my second style. For that one I have the following selectors:

```
.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .tab-header-background  (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab  (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab > .tab-label (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab:selected  (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab:hover  (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab:selected > .tab-label (...)
.main-tab-pane > .tab:hover  (...)
```

I have a "main" `TabPane`, where `styleClass="main-tab-pane"`. I**nside this `TabPane`** I have a "normal" one.

The result, however, is not the one I expected: the first `TabPane` gets the style corresponding to `.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .tab-header-background` and the second one the one corresponding to `.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .tab-header-background  (...)`.

However, **all the tabs get the behavior of** `.main-tab-pane > .tab * (...)`! In other words, `.main-tab-pane > .tab` overrides `.tab`.

My question is: how could I keep these two styles separate from each other, specially regarding the style of the tabs? I would prefer it if the answers involved FXML or CSS solutions, but Java code is also welcome.

Comment: The second `TabPane` is placed inside of the "main" `TabPane`, am I correct? Otherwise it is not possible, so guess I.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by the proper usage of the `>` (direct children) operator, and by following the css structure of the `TabPane` defined in [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) (`TabPane` section):

```
// For tabs in general
.tab { -fx-background-color: red; }
.tab .tab-label { -fx-text-fill: yellow;}
.tab:hover { -fx-background-color: cyan; }

// Only for the main tab-pane
.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:hover {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.main-tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region >  .tab > .tab-container >  .tab-label{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

These selectors define the generic style for every `Tab` and the special style for the `Tab`s that are **direct children** of `TabPanes` having the `main-tab-pane` CSS style class. This means, even if you embed an another `TabPane` inside the "main" one, the specified selectors will not select the embedded one, therefore the CSS styles will be not inherited.

**Example**

The two `TabPane`s are created like:

```
TabPane main = new TabPane();
main.getStyleClass().add("main-tab-pane");
Tab mainTab = new Tab("MainTab");
main.getTabs().add(mainTab);
mainTab.setContent(new TabPane(new Tab("SecondTab")));
```

And the result: untouched -> main tab hover -> inner tab hover.

[image]

---

Another possibility is, **if you dont have to have the first style as a default for all of the `TabPane`s in you application** is to is to create a second style-class that is attached to the inner `TabPane`:

```
// Main tab-pane
.main-tab-pane .tab { -fx-background-color: blue; }
.main-tab-pane .tab:hover { -fx-background-color: green; }
.main-tab-pane .tab .tab-label {-fx-text-fill: white; }

// Inner tab-pane
.inner-tab-pane .tab { -fx-background-color: red; }
.inner-tab-pane .tab .tab-label { -fx-text-fill: yellow; }
.inner-tab-pane .tab:hover { -fx-background-color: cyan; }
```

and create the `TabPane`s like:

```
TabPane main = new TabPane();
main.getStyleClass().add("main-tab-pane");
Tab mainTab = new Tab("MainTab");
main.getTabs().add(mainTab);
TabPane secondTab = new TabPane(new Tab("SecondTab"));
secondTab.getStyleClass().add("inner-tab-pane");
mainTab.setContent(secondTab);
```

For these two `TabPane`s the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As an advice you should use Sass to make it more clear and easier.

For your question it should be like this :

```
.main-tab-pane .tab {
   color: red;
}
.second-tab-pane .tab {
   color: blue;
}
```

Then make sure that your tab element is INSIDE of a 'mainOrSecond'-tab-pane